# An inequality involving $\max$, $\min$, product and sum

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, real-numbers, lattice-orders

Given four real numbers $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\in\mathbb R$ I wonder if in general:

$$ (x_1\lor y_1) (x_2 \lor y_2) + (x_1 \land y_1) (x_2\land y_2) \geq x_1 x_2+y_1 y_2\,.$$

When we restrict ourself to binary variables $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\in\{-1,1\}$ the previous inequality can be checked directly (any smarter idea?). Is it still true for real variables?

Comment: This is a rearrangement inequality (and is true in general). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Comment: @mvenzin thanks a lot

Comment: @mvenzin for $f(x):=(x^2 -1)^2$ is it still true that $f(x\lor y)+f(x\land y)\geq f(x)+f(y)$? Does not seem to fall in rearrangement inequalities. Is there a general way to check if $f$ has this property?

Comment: This should always be true, regardless of the function $f$!

Comment: @mvenzin I don't see why. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: Very simple, suppose $x \geq y$ (otherwise change $x$ by $y$) $f(\max(x,y)) +f(\min(x,y)) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: @mvenzin Oh sure, thank you